# How to define a specific application to open a pdf from excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to automate the opening of a pdf which is defined using a dynamic hyperlink, but using the DEFAULT pdf editor of the user, but cannot fathom how to do this beyond the code below which opens the file in

I have other code to save the pdf which automatically saves it and opens a file in the default program for each user.  But I don't know how to do the reverse and have a file which is searched for and found via the dynamic hyperlink - which will then allow them to update.

This is to shortcut sometone opening various folders, manually seatching, then opening up a file.  ideally Id want to automate.

Here is the code I have so far which works but will only open in Adobe and not the default program - is this perhaps a setting thing on my PC or is it code which is missing?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TNR Report")
Dim r As Range: Set r = ws.Range("A82") ' this defines the actual path and filename to be searched for

Dim strHyperlink As String
On Error GoTo CannotFindFile
strHyperlink = r.Value
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink strHyperlink
```

File needs to open with nuance to enable the user to edit and update the "record", but opens only in reader which is no use and kind of defeats the purpose of the code.

Comment: *I have other code to save the pdf which automatically saves it and opens a file in the default program for each user*. Can you include this snippet of code? It seems like you should be able to adapt that approach, rather than using `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink` use the other method to open the `strHyperlink` filename.

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities:

1. Make *Nuance* your default application in Windows to open PDF files.
2. Use a shell command to start nuance with a filename as parameter

   ```
   Shell """C:\Path To Nuance\Nuance.exe"" ""C:\Path To PDF\pdffile.pdf"""
   ```

Comment: PEH - option one has already been done on every users PC - still opens the file with reader!   Second one may well be different on all users PC?

Comment: @RobertW081171 Actually if the hyperlink points to the pdf file only, it should always open in the default pdf application. Try to restart the computer after changing the default application.

Comment: OK I will try - its strange as my PC is set to have nuance as the default pdf application and it still opened in reader.  But let me try and I will post the result soon

Comment: Please also test by double clicking the PDF file in the Windows Explorer if it opens in Nuance or Reader (and post the result).

Comment: still opening in adobe reader, but opens in nuance any other way I try.

Comment: Actually that's very strange. It should use the default application.

Comment: That's why I am totally confused.

Comment: @RobertW081171 If I run `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "c:\temp\test.pdf"` it opens the file in whatever App I change my default pdf application to.

Comment: won't in my PC - hence why I wanted a method of defining the application

Comment: Then you can probably only use the second method I suggested.

Comment: issue I can foresee with option 2 is how do I make this sufficiently dynamic to capture this on every users PC?  I would imagine the location should be the same, but.....